# While loop - two conditions: return empty string "" or null from prompt

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am trying to create a while loop that stops when the return value from prompt = null or an empty string " ".

```
var inputName = prompt("Enter a name", "");
var namesArray = [];

while (inputName != "" || inputName != null) {
  inputName;
  namesArray[namesArray.length] = inputName;
}

namesArray.sort();

var namesList = namesArray.join("<br/>");

document.write(namesList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is likely using the wrong operator (it should be using `&&` to makes sure BOTH conditions are met) and there are other issues too because you never change the value of `inputName` inside the loop so if you did enter the `while()` loop, you would loop forever.

I'd suggest changing your `if` statement to test for a `falsey` value and that will automatically catch both the conditions you care about.  And here's a generally cleaner implementation:

```
var namesArray = [], inputName;
while(true) {
    inputName = prompt("Enter a name", "");
    if (!inputName) {
        break;
    }
    namesArray.push(inputName);
}
namesArray.sort();
document.write(namesArray.join("<br/>"));
```

---

The structure `if (!inputName)` will test for any falsey value of `inputName` which includes `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `NaN`, `false`.  Since you are specifically interested in `null` and `""`, this will cover those more simply.  See [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) for more info on falsey.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||` otherwise it leads to infinite loop.Also you can use `do..while` here, that will be best suitable option for you.

```js
var inputName;
var namesArray = [];

do {
  inputName = prompt("Enter a name", "");
  if (inputName != "" && inputName != null) // check value is null or empty
    namesArray.push(inputName);
} while (inputName != "" && inputName != null);

namesArray.sort();

var namesList = namesArray.join("<br/>");

document.write(namesList);
```

---

Or using your same code you need to put `prompt` inside while

```js
var inputName = prompt("Enter a name", "");
var namesArray = [];

while (inputName != "" && inputName != null) {
  //                  --^-- you need to use && here
  namesArray.push(inputName); // push the value to array
  inputName = prompt("Enter a name", ""); // prompt for new value
}

namesArray.sort();

var namesList = namesArray.join("<br/>");

document.write(namesList);
```

Comment: Note, this will `push` a `null` value at the end of the loop.